# wet floor in bathroom

Tags: leak

I tiled a bath room can I get leak from the tile grout?
I wake up in the morning and I find a small puddle of water by my tub.
We take showers and wipe up the floor after we are done at night.

Comment: If there is water still on the shower walls it may be dripping down , not sure about grout leaking if sealed a tile tub could hold water but that would be unusual for a tile bathtub but have seen them.

Comment: Where is the water? Perhaps a photo would help us understand and diagnose the situation.

Comment: How long ago did you tile the room (floor, walls, both?)? Did you have this problem before tiling?